# Pytorch says that optimizer got an empty parameter list

Tags: python, pytorch

**Here I make model**

```
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
def _init_(self,num_classes=6):
    super(ConvNet,self)._init_()
    self.conv1=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,out_channels=12,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1)
    self.bn1=nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=12)
    self.relu1=nn.ReLU()

    self.pool=nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)

    self.conv2=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=12,out_channels=20,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1)
    self.relu2=nn.ReLU()

    self.conv3=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=20,out_channels=32,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1)
    self.bn3=nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=32)
    self.relu3=nn.ReLU()
    self.fc=nn.Linear(in_features=32*75*75,out_features=num_classes)
```

**forward step**

```
def forward(self,input):
    output=self.conv1(input)
    output=self.bn1(output)
    output=self.relul(output)

    output=self.pool(output)

    output=self.conv2(output)
    output=self.relu2(output)

    output=self.conv3(output)
    output=self.bn3(output)
    output=self.relu3(output)
```

**Here is my output**

```
    output=output.view(-1,32*75*75)

    output=self.fc(output)

    return output

model=ConvNet().to(device)
```

**Here i train my model**

```
 loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
 optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3, weight_decay=0.0001)
```

**But I got error**

However, when I try to put the parameters in a optimizer class I get this error:

```
ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list
```

Answer (score 0):

You typed the constructor incorrectly - you missed the double underscore.

It should look like this:

```
def __init__(self,num_classes=6):
    super(ConvNet,self).__init__()
```